# Glibc-2.17 toolchain issue iconv folder undefined reference

Tags: glibc

On building Glibc on my toolchain . The libraries make succesfully (and test ok) all FLAGS unset except for those specified for building default glibc. then i start building the programs both with and without FLAGS on seperate fresh build attempts and every time something in the iconv folder always breaks...

I'll diverge for a second to moan how its always iconv that breaks in GLibc for me and always has done for as long as i can remember... moving on though....

When gcc-4.8.0 is passed gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /glibc-build/iconv/iconvconfig  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel,--fatal-warnings /glibc-build/csu/Scrt1.o /glibc-build/csu/crti.o `gcc --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o` /glibc-build/iconv/iconvconfig.o /glibc-build/iconv/strtab.o /glibc-build/iconv/xmalloc.o /glibc-build/iconv/hash-string.o  -Wl,-rpath-link=/glibc-build:/glibc-build/math:/glibc-build/elf:/glibc-build/dlfcn:/glibc-build/nss:/glibc-build/nis:/glibc-build/rt:/glibc-build/resolv:/glibc-build/crypt:/glibc-build/nptl /glibc-build/libc.so.6 /glibc-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /glibc-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  --print-file-name=crtendS.o` /glibc-build/csu/crtn.o
gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /glibc-build/iconv/iconv_prog  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel,--fatal-warnings /mnt/lfs/glibc-build/csu/Scrt1.o /glibc-build/csu/crti.o `gcc --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o` /glibc-build/iconv/iconv_prog.o /glibc-build/iconv/iconv_charmap.o /glibc-build/iconv/charmap.o /glibc-build/iconv/charmap-dir.o /glibc-build/iconv/linereader.o /glibc-build/iconv/dummy-repertoire.o /glibc-build/iconv/simple-hash.o /glibc-build/iconv/xstrdup.o /glibc-build/iconv/xmalloc.o  -Wl,-rpath-link=/glibc-build:/glibc-build/math:/glibc-build/elf:/glibc-build/dlfcn:/glibc-build/nss:/glibc-build/nis:/glibc-build/rt:/glibc-build/resolv:/glibc-build/crypt:/glibc-build/nptl /glibc-build/libc.so.6 /glibc-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /glibc-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  --print-file-name=crtendS.o` /glibc-build/csu/crtn.o

i get 2 pages of  referencing issues

/glibc-build/iconv/iconvconfig.o: In function `more_help':
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to`__tsan_func_entry'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `__tsan_write8'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to`__tsan_func_exit'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `__tsan_read8'
/glibc-build/iconv/iconvconfig.o: In function`alias_compare':
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x226): undefined reference to `__tsan_func_entry'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to`__tsan_read1'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `__tsan_read8'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to`__tsan_read1'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x26e): undefined reference to `__tsan_read8'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x282): undefined reference to`__tsan_func_exit'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x2b4): undefined reference to `__asan_report_load8'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to`__asan_report_load8'
/glibc-build/iconv/iconvconfig.o: In function `module_compare':
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x2fb): undefined reference to`__tsan_func_entry'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x308): undefined reference to `__tsan_read1'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x326): undefined reference to`__tsan_read8'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x337): undefined reference to `__tsan_read1'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x34a): undefined reference to`__tsan_read8'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `__tsan_func_exit'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x3a6): undefined reference to`__asan_report_load8'
iconvconfig.c:(.text+0x3ab): undefined reference to `__asan_report_load8'
/glibc-build/iconv/iconvconfig.o: In function`name_compare':

after 2 weeks of trying to get it to compile every which way possible im getting a bit fed up. Any ideas please?

Emma

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but hopefully useful.

The symbols with tsan and asan in their name are related to the [address sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) project that provides LLVM clang and gcc with tools to detect and report a whole range of problems related to illegal memory access.

To use them you have to install tools and libraries, use the correct versions of the compilers and the correct combinations of flags during compile and linking depending on your version.

In my experience the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/Flags) is only so useful, and the topic is pretty advanced. In my project over which I have full control, I ended up disabling all but the one commandline parameter `-fsanitize=address` together with the recommended `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` for both compile and link (gcc 4.8 on x64 ubuntu 14.04LTS).

Since you are attempting to build an existing project, you are at the mercy of their settings. I would look at docs for that project and try to determine the recommended versions of compiler and sanitizer tools from there, or maybe some configuration options to disable it if you don't care.